# What is the main difference of a sound wave propagating in air and in water?

Tags: waves, speed-of-light, symmetry, refraction

I was reading [this article](https://dosits.org/science/sounds-in-the-sea/how-does-sound-in-air-differ-from-sound-in-water/) out of curiosity and I started wandering about the key difference in the propagation of a sound wave in water.
 Maybe something due to the fact that very rarely we have a "symmetric" region of space and I suppose that water is even less symmetric than air, with a lot of complications in the application of [Huygens Fresnel principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle).

Also, I know that from thermodynamics we can extract a relation between speed of sound wave and temperature:
$$v=\sqrt\alpha T$$
$\alpha \approx 20$. Is there something similar for water? Or maybe some empirical relation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed of sound in pure water as a function of temperature:

V= 1404.3 + 4.7 T - 0.04 T*T
where T is between 15 to 35 degrees Centigrade, and V in m/s

see

http://resource.npl.co.uk/acoustics/techguides/soundpurewater/content.html#LUBBERS

which contains many other formulas

Answer (score -2):

> ***Here is your answer,***

***In air, it will not propagate much faster than water due to density of water.***

Comment: Sorry, but I think the question is looking for something much more substantial than this.